# Can you get object details using readelf?

Tags: elf

I'm looking to get a specific field of a struct from an elf file. I've found the object:

```
1009b184     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 $d
1009b184     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 __init___device_cros_system_npcx_0
```

The struct has 2 fields: `.init` and `.device`, I want to get the `.init` field without having to "just know" that it is the first 4 bytes. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this?

If the file is compiled with debug info, then `readelf -wi` will print the info needed to reconstruct the type and offsets within the type.

Without debug info: no.